# Pasar la propiedad de un objeto a un método

Tags: c#

Quiero crear un método en el que pueda poner cierta propiedad de un objeto, algo así

```
class Auto
{
    public int RuedasAuto;
    public int Ventanas;
    public string Patente;
    public Auto(int ruedas, int ventanas)
    {
        RuedasAuto = ruedas;
        Ventanas = ventanas;
    }
    
}

class Procesador
{
    public static void Metodo(string propiedad)
    {
        if (propiedad == Auto.RuedasAuto)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Tu auto tiene {RuedasAuto} ruedas");
        }
    }
}
```

Y lo que quiero hacer es similar a esto

```
Auto auto = new Auto(4, 6);
Procesador.Metodo(auto.RuedasAuto)
```

Quería usar Func<> pero cómo soy un poco nuevo no lo sé hacer

Comment: Con qué objetivo deseas utilizar `Func<>`?

Comment: Vos queres que segun la propiedad que pasaste hacer algo en particular? pone un ejemplo mas claro, porque no entiendo si necesitas reflection u otra cosa

Comment: pues podrias hacer  MuestraPropiedad(obj propiedad)  {var nomPropiedad=nameof(propiedad) // y luego tus ifs}

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que necesitas es crear un método que reciba el nombre de una propiedad y a partir de este obtener el valor de dicha propiedad en el objeto. Si es así, se podría hacer lo siguiente:

```
class Procesador
{
    public static void Metodo(string propiedad, Auto auto)
    {
        if (propiedad == nameof(auto.RuedasAuto))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(auto.RuedasAuto);
        }
    }
}
```

Y para usarlo podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
Auto auto = new Auto(4, 6);
Procesador.Metodo(nameof(auto.RuedasAuto), auto)
```

En la práctica sería algo así: [Ejemplo código](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uKd7NU)

**Edición:** En atención a los comentarios:

1. Esta sería la alternativa con reflection (lo demás se mantiene igual):

```
class Procesador
{
    public static void Metodo(string propiedad, Auto auto)
    {   
        var valor = auto.GetType().GetField(propiedad).GetValue(auto);
        Console.WriteLine(valor);
    }
}
```

2. Tomar en cuenta que nameof está [disponible desde C# 6](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) ([lanzada con VS2015](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history#c-version-60))

Comment: Esto deberia hacerse por reflection, no asi...

Comment: Lo que planteas no es correcto, pero además el  nameof existe desde las más nuevas versiones de c#, si el usuario estuviera usando c# 5 el nameof no serviria